# what does "ignoreKotlinNullability" actually do?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, realm

At one point in our project's development, I've added since section to our gradle:

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("realm.ignoreKotlinNullability", true)
    }
}
```

I recall doing this to prevent crashes during migration, and looking it up online proved that to be it's main use.

But what does it actually do? I can't find any official docs anywhere to prove and assumptions. I'm not sure if I should remove it or not since I don't know if I should treat it as a feature or some sort of bandaid I've applied a long time ago.

Is there an official list of RealmDB gradle flags and arguments anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Kotlin, then Realm checks against nullability on your field.

For example,

```
class Blah: RealmObject() {
    var group: Group? = null
}
```

Then group doesn't get implicit @Required annotation.

But if you do

```
class Blah: RealmObject() {
    var group: Group = Group()
}
```

This won't work, because Realm cannot guarantee non-nullability for a singular link. So it'll throw the error you're getting.

If you want to ignore this because for example you are making a backing field that avoids null value return

```
kapt {
  arguments {
    arg("realm.ignoreKotlinNullability", true)
  }
}
```

In which case Realm won't try to handle your nullability implicitly (and map the Kotlin nullability to the field's @Required). But you should use this only if you actually know what you're doing.